# Do we have any method to know whether the protractor script is currently running or not

Tags: batch-file, protractor, windows-task-scheduler

I need to execute the protractor script automatically from windows task scheduler at particular time intervals. 
I can do that by giving command(protractor conf.js) in a batch file. *But* i need to check whether the protractor script is currently running or not. 
 If it not in a running mode then only i need to execute the batch file. 
How can i do this? Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `schtasks.exe` or the GUI interface to setup the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three options:

1. Run `%windir%\system32\taskschd.msc /s`, drill-down to your task entry, right-click and select properties from the drop-down menu. Select the settings tab and select `Do not start a new instance` in the drop-down selection box under `If the task is already running, then the following rule applies:`.
2. Add the `<MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>` element to the `<Settings>` group in your task XML file and import that.
3. Set the MultipleInstancesPolicy setting via whatever script/code you're using to create the task. See [ITaskSettings::put_MultipleInstances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-itasksettings-put_multipleinstances).